# hide a div under youtube iframe on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

I would hide 'div .blind' on click on youtube video(on 'div #player'). How can i do it?

for example:

```js
JS:
...
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
 player = new YT.Player('player', {
  videoId: 'Lo3rrP8u7Mw',
  playerVars: {
   'wmode': 'transparent',
   'color': 'white',
   'modestbranding': 1,
   'showinfo': 1

  },
  events: {
   'onReady': onPlayerReady,
   'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
  }
 });
...
```

```css
CSS:
.video .blind {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  }
```

```html
HTML:
<div class="video">
  <div id="player" ></div>
  <div class="blind" id="blind"></div>
</div>

<div class="video">
  <div id="player2" ></div>
  <div class="blind" id="blind"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: .video:focus .blind{display: none}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you mean with "click on youtube video" I assume you want to hide your element while the video is playing?

The best implementation would be to change the display state of your element by listenting to the `onStateChange` event.

You could implement the following code in your `onPlayerStateChange` function:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    let strDisplay = event.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING ? 'none' : 'block';
    document.querySelector('.blind').style.display = strDisplay;
}
```

See also https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#onStateChange